# Tourist renting a Citroen Ami in France

Tags: france, car-rentals

The tiny Citroen Ami is receiving a lot of attention recently.  I am tempted to buy one but renting one in France first would be sensible to check whether we could really live with it.  At the very least, it should be a fun vacation activity even if the answer is that we do not want one.

When: no particular time considered yet.  We will probably wait for travel to become easier.

Where: two possibilities.  A short rental in Paris during a quiet period such as Sunday morning for a little city tour.  A longer rental to explore quieter areas of the country.

Me: dual UK / Irish citizen, full UK licence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130326/discussion-on-question-by-badjohn-tourist-renting-a-citroen-ami-in-france). The comments here had become more of a chat, which is what that chatroom is for. Comments here locked for now, but you can post in the chatroom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Free2move](https://www.free2move.com/en-GB/free-floating-car-sharing-paris) has some Citroen Ami as part of their fleet of cars in Paris. You might have to walk a bit to find one as I have the feeling the Citroen C-Zéro are much more common.

I believe you can even register with their [UK branch](https://www.free2move.com/en-GB/free-floating-car-sharing-paris), completing all necessary formalities (uploading a driving license, taking a verfication selfie) and use the same account while you are in Paris. I have not tried this particular combination (Free2move, UK -> France) but I did complete their registration process with a foreign license and I have used a competing services (ShareNow) across several countries with one account so they are definitely open to non-residents (ShareNow only has Smart EQ fortwo or forfour in Paris so it is not a good fit for your purpose).

The rental prices are not that attractive if you want to keep the car several hours or go to the countryside but it is in principle possible. You can in any case easily go for a 30-min test drive in the city for €10 or so and drop the car wherever you want inside Paris. The small size is definitely a big plus when it comes to finding a parking spot.

Note that since the Citroen Ami is not classified as a car in France, you are not allowed to drive one on the Paris ring road (*boulevard périphérique*). In spite of the fact that it can technically be driven without a driving license, I also believe Free2move requires one from its customers (possibly for insurance purposes or because they won't restrict your account to a small part of their fleet).

Comment: It is not expected that it will be classed as a car in the UK either.  That is both a pro and a con.  Regardless of the legality. I would not take it on the Périphérique.

Comment: @badjohn I thought so but it seemed useful to mention that. I also added a note on driving licenses that might help you with the question regarding your wife. A driving license is required in this case but AFAIK the requirement is not a legal one, it's part of Free2move terms and conditions.

Comment: The licence requirement is unsurprising and not a serious problem.  We can still have a little fun and get an idea of whether one of these things would be useful back home.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citro%C3%ABn_Ami_(electric) - seems like a license is required if you were born after 1988

Comment: @JonathanReez True. Note that it's not a full driving license, there is no exam, just a mandatory theory training that French kids get in school and a two-day practical training in a driving school. It could still be a hurdle for (young) tourists, though. All this is moot when rentals require a driving license.

Comment: A 75km range seems like it'd be a bigger problem than the hourly rental charges if trying to leave the city.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Other cars in their fleet have longer ranges and I can imagine many scenarios where even the Ami's limited range wouldn't be a huge problem whereas the hourly rate still would (say spending the day at Disneyland or Versailles).